# Transform map M into array of maps A where keys and values from M are mapped to new keys in elements in A

Tags: clojure

Given a map like this:

```
{
 "keystring1" "valuestring1"
 "keystring2" "valuestring2"
 ...
}
```

How can I transform it into an array of maps like this:

```
[
 {
  :newKey1 "keystring1"
  :newKey2 "valuestring1"
 }
 {
  :newKey1 "keystring2"
  :newKey2 "valuestring2"
 }
 ...
]
```

From my research I assume the functions `reduce-kv` and `assoc` should be useful here, but I couldn't create a working version yet.

The closes I've gotten so far is:

```
 (reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
   (merge m (assoc {} :newkey1 k) (assoc {} :newkey2 v)))
   []
   {"keystring1" "valuestring1", "keystring2" "valuestring2"})
```

Which results in:

```
[{:newkey1 "keystring1"} {:newkey2 "valuestring1"} {:newkey1 "keystring2"} {:newkey2 "valuestring2"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `reduce-kv`:

```
(def my-map
  {"keystring1" "valuestring1"
   "keystring2" "valuestring2"})

(reduce-kv
  (fn [acc k v] (conj acc {:newKey1 k :newKey2 v}))
  []
  my-map)
```

Or using `zipmap`:

```
(mapv #(zipmap [:newKey1 :newKey2] %) my-map)
```

Both produce this:

```
=> [{:newKey1 "keystring1", :newKey2 "valuestring1"}
    {:newKey1 "keystring2", :newKey2 "valuestring2"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution using mapv and zipmap is really neat!

Comment: FWIW I'd go with the `for` approach. I just added these as alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use `for` for things like this.

```
(def m {"keystring1" "valuestring1"
        "keystring2" "valuestring2"})

> (for [[k v] m]
    {:newkey1 k
     :newkey2 v})

({:newkey1 "keystring1", :newkey2 "valuestring1"}
 {:newkey1 "keystring2", :newkey2 "valuestring2"})
```

You can force it to be a vector if really needed:

```
> (vec (for [[k v] m]
         {:newkey1 k
          :newkey2 v}))

[{:newkey1 "keystring1", :newkey2 "valuestring1"}
 {:newkey1 "keystring2", :newkey2 "valuestring2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

and one more, for completeness:

```
user> (map (partial zipmap [:new-key1 :new-key2]) data)

;;=> ({:new-key1 "keystring1", :new-key2 "valuestring1"} 
;;    {:new-key1 "keystring2", :new-key2 "valuestring2"})
```

or

```
user> (map zipmap (repeat [:new-key1 :new-key2]) data)

;;=> ({:new-key1 "keystring1", :new-key2 "valuestring1"} 
;;    {:new-key1 "keystring2", :new-key2 "valuestring2"})
```